# How to format the columns in sqlplus while displaying it in the terminal?

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, formatting, sqlplus

I was using the HR account in the Oracle DB XE on Ubuntu.
So I am running the SQL*Plus in the terminal.
I know that the maximum displayable linesize is 150 without wrapping
but when I display the employee table in the terminal the last two columns end up wrapping around.
I have

```
set lines 150;
set trimout on;
set pagesize 10000;
set tab off;
set wrap on;
```

and I am seeing
[image: displaying the columns]

as you can see here the columns LAST_NAME, EMAIL, HIRE_DATE are taking extra blank spaces which could be other wise utilized for displaying the columns which get wrapped.
I tried flicking the wrap on and off and that doesn’t help either.
How can I optimize the space consumed as I am also spooling the file and the output is very confusing to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
COLUMN LAST_NAME FORMAT A10
```

/

for limit to 10 alfanum char

Comment: thank you for your response, it worked. but i was wondering whether this limit affected while displaying only or even while inserting new elements?

Comment: hey i messed up. i did the above query with a number column and  now its just returning # signs in that particular column. the employee_id column only had 3 digit numbers to begin with so i went in with A5 but now this. help

Comment: You mean column with integer or number value content?

Comment: yes, if you look in the picture the first column aka EMPLOYEE_ID has 3 digit numbers. so i formatted with A5. now i am getting #######

Comment: try with  COLUMN EMPLOYEE_DI FORMAT  999

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99544/discussion-between-chris-jay-and-scaisedge).